How does a signal get amplified?
Say I send an analog electric signal through a telephone wire. If that wire is long enough then the resistance will eventually make the amplitude of the signal close to zero. How do electric signals gain energy without losing the characteristic wave form? (I'm looking for both simple and technical answers, along with any circuits).
I can understand this in digital modulation since its binary but in analog copying a waveform perplexes me, the closest I can come up with is a step up transformer.

We would use an amplifier.  The amplifier uses external power to increase the amplitude of a signal.
You will have amplifiers in your cell phone, Hi-Fi audio system and in many other devices.


If that wire is long enough then the resistance will eventually make the amplitude of the signal close to zero.

Ohm's law relates amplitude (voltage), resistance ... and current. When the resistance is fixed, e.g. in a length of wire, the current and voltage drop are proportional. By reducing the current, the voltage drop is reduced as well. Even in the era of vacuum tubes, keeping the DC input current very low was not a problem. A properly designed differential pair input has DC impedance in the MΩ range. So, the wires can be very long without much voltage loss due to the low current.
That's at DC. Above 0Hz, i.e. for AC voltages, there is some amount of distributed capacitance between the wires in each pair (long distance circuits use pairs of wires). This capacitance causes an AC current to flow that grows with frequency. There's not much that can be done to get this capacitance significantly reduced. We may reduce it by an order of magnitude and not much more by varying the construction of the cable. So we need a more fundamental improvement.
This can be tackled by matching the source and load impedance to the characteristic impedance of the transmission line (e.g. the pair of wires in a long distance circuit). The characteristic impedance is an AC property, and cannot be measured with a DC ohmmeter. When the source and load are matched to the characteristic impedance, the transmission line becomes transparent, i.e. its distributed capacitance and inductance vanish, and the source "sees" exactly the resistive load impedance:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
That's for an ideal transmission line. Real transmission lines are lossy, i.e. each unit length of the line converts a bit of signal energy into heat. When the line us very long, these losses become significant.
That's where we need "analog waveform copiers". An ideal "waveform copier" is called a Voltage-Controlled Voltage Source (VCVS). Real "copiers" are called amplifiers and can come pretty close to this ideal. E.g. an operational amplifier can do a very good job as such a "copier".
Amplifiers can do this job because they are furnished with an external source of energy, and they typically present very little loading on their input.


How do electric signals gain energy without losing the characteristic
wave form? (I'm looking for both simple and technical answers, along
with any circuits).

You need an active element that can add energy, and amplify the signal. For electrical signals this is commonly done with voltage amplification. In modern times operational amplifiers are the most common way of amplifying, and provide a gain to a voltage so if you have a 1V sine wave and a gain of 10V/V you would get a 10V sine wave out (assuming that the opamp can provide a 10V output).
Transformers can also amplify but they can only amplify AC signals whereas opamps can amplify DC and AC signals.

My definition of amplifier is that the output power from the device is higher than the input power. For that reason I  don't include transformers in the list of things that amplify. It can increase the voltage (or current, but not both) magnitude but does not have power gain.

Yes, this is true. You can have voltage amplifiers and current amplifiers I suppose.

A step up transformer is a good start.
It will provide higher output voltage, but it will also provide lower current so it will be useless unless provided with ability to drive more current.
Therefore you still need a buffer amplifier to do something useful with the signal, which uses external power to provide same signal voltage out but with ability to drive more current.
But there are other kind of amplifiers as well. You could use an amplifier with voltage gain in place of the step up transformer.
Take a standard op-amp for example. They can receive weak input amplitudes and apply gain when configured properly with external components.

Energy loss in wires

If that wire is long enough then the resistance will eventually make the amplitude of the signal close to zero.

Exactly! Imagine how the current I of the input signal Vin flows through the resistance of the (telephone) wire Rl and a voltage drop VRl = I.Rl is lost across it. As a result, the voltage VL across the load RL will be VL = Vin - VRl instead Vin.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
To visualize the voltage drops without complicating the schematic, let's simulate the line and load resistances through "deliberately degraded voltmeters" with internal resistances Rl = 1 kΩ and RL = 1 kΩ.

simulate this circuit
How do we gain energy?

How do electric signals gain energy without losing the characteristic wave form?

There are two ways to "gain energy" - by adding energy (power, voltage) and by regulating energy. I will take a closer look at the first one because it is not very well known.
Adding energy to the input signal
It is easy to guess that since voltage is lost across Rl (subtracted from Vin), we can add the same voltage Vcomp = VRl, and thus compensate for the losses. As a result, the voltage drop across the compensated line Vlcomp will be 0 V, and the voltage across the load RL will be VL = Vin - VRl + VRl = Vin.

simulate this circuit
But the voltage drop across the wire varies. So, we have to connect a "proportional" voltage source that follows VRl and produces a "mirror" voltage -VRl with negative polarity. We can use the so-called "behavioral voltage source" from the CircuitLab library.

simulate this circuit
We can say also that the compensating voltage source produces voltage Vcomp = -I.Rl.

simulate this circuit
From this viewpoint, the compensating voltage source has the behavior of a "negative resistor" with resistance -Rl which adds voltage proportional to the current as opposed to a positive resistor Rl which subtracts voltage proportional to current. As a result, the two resistances cancel each other out and the result is zero (the line behaves as an "ideal conductor").

simulate this circuit
Regulating energy of an additional voltage source
This is a more conventional way of "amplifying" than the extravagant one above. In this case, we take a power source with a voltage higher than the maximum input voltage, and connect in series a regulating element (variable "resistor") controlled by the input voltage. Thus, part of the supply voltage is lost on it and the rest appears "amplified" across the load.
